# Why my query cost is so high?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, optimization

When I execute explain analyze on some query I've got the normal cost from some low value to some higher value. But when I'm trying to force to use the index on table by switching enable_seqscan to false, the query cost jumps to insane values like:

```
Merge Join  (cost=10064648609.460..10088218360.810 rows=564249 width=21) (actual time=341699.323..370702.969 rows=3875328 loops=1)
    Merge Cond: ((foxtrot.two = ((five_hotel.two)::numeric)) AND (foxtrot.alpha_two07 = ((five_hotel.alpha_two07)::numeric)))
  ->  Merge Append  (cost=10000000000.580..10023064799.260 rows=23522481 width=24) (actual time=0.049..19455.320 rows=23522755 loops=1)
          Sort Key: foxtrot.two, foxtrot.alpha_two07
        ->  Sort  (cost=10000000000.010..10000000000.010 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
                Sort Key: foxtrot.two, foxtrot.alpha_two07
                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Seq Scan on foxtrot  (cost=10000000000.000..10000000000.000 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                      Filter: (kilo_sierra_oscar = 'oscar'::date)
        ->  Index Scan using alpha_five on five_uniform  (cost=0.560..22770768.220 rows=23522480 width=24) (actual time=0.043..17454.619 rows=23522755 loops=1)
                Filter: (kilo_sierra_oscar = 'oscar'::date)
```

As you can see I'm trying to retrive values by index, so they doesn't need to be sorted once they're loaded.

It is a simple query:

```
select *
    from foxtrot a
      where foxtrot.kilo_sierra_oscar = date'2015-01-01'
      order by foxtrot.two, foxtrot.alpha_two07
```

> Index scan: "Execution time: 19009.569 ms"
>
> Sequential scan: "Execution time: 127062.802 ms"

Setting the enable_seqscan to false improves execution time of query, but I would like optimizer to calculate that.

**EDIT:**

Seq plan with buffers:

```
Sort  (cost=4607555.110..4666361.310 rows=23522481 width=24) (actual time=101094.754..120740.190 rows=23522756 loops=1)
    Sort Key: foxtrot.two, foxtrot.alpha07
    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 805304kB
    Buffers: shared hit=468690, temp read=100684 written=100684
  ->  Append  (cost=0.000..762721.000 rows=23522481 width=24) (actual time=0.006..12018.725 rows=23522756 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=468690
        ->  Seq Scan on foxtrot  (cost=0.000..0.000 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                Filter: (kilo = 'oscar'::date)
        ->  Seq Scan on foxtrot (cost=0.000..762721.000 rows=23522480 width=24) (actual time=0.005..9503.851 rows=23522756 loops=1)
                Filter: (kilo = 'oscar'::date)
                Buffers: shared hit=468690
```

Index plan with buffers:

```
Merge Append  (cost=10000000000.580..10023064799.260 rows=23522481 width=24) (actual time=0.046..19302.855 rows=23522756 loops=1)
    Sort Key: foxtrot.two, foxtrot.alpha_two07
    Buffers: shared hit=17855133   ->  Sort  (cost=10000000000.010..10000000000.010 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
          Sort Key: foxtrot.two, foxtrot.alpha_two07
          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Seq Scan on foxtrot  (cost=10000000000.000..10000000000.000 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)
                Filter: (kilo = 'oscar'::date)
        ->  Index Scan using alpha_five on five  (cost=0.560..22770768.220 rows=23522480 width=24) (actual time=0.036..17035.903 rows=23522756 loops=1)
          Filter: (kilo = 'oscar'::date)
          Buffers: shared hit=17855133
```

Why the cost of the query jumps so high? How can I avoid it?

Comment: can you add the output of `explain (analyze, buffers)`?

Comment: `order by foxtrot.two, foxtrot.alpha_two07` foxtrot is not part of your from clause. Please post the real query.

Comment: Excuse me, I was trying to update the query to anonymized plan from `explain.depesz.com`. Now it's okay.

Comment: Your name replacements still aren't consistent with each other. Is the first query and its description in your question still relevant?

Comment: And what is `five` ? Still incoherent. (my gut feeling says that you have random names in your fromclause/rangetable and are executing random carthesian products)

Comment: `Five` is `Foxtrot` - explain.depesz.com does think it's two tables, but it's the sub for seq scan on foxtrot.

Comment: `((foxtrot.two = ((five_hotel.two)::numeric))` This looks like a join of **two tables** . with two *different* column types. Is there any view involved, BTW? (IOW: add the table definitions to your question)

Comment: yes, the first query was the section from the bigger one. Drop it down to one table to show what I'm meaning.

Comment: It seems your query returns milions of rows. Why would you do that?

Comment: @JakubKania 'cause later I'm going to aggregate it anyway :)

Comment: Stop wasting everyone's time and post the real query if you're hoping for help. The plan you posted has a join; the query does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The high cost is a direct consequence of `set enable_seqscan=false`.

The planner implements this "hint" by setting an arbitrary super-high cost (`10 000 000 000`) to the sequential scan technique. Then it computes the different potential execution strategies with  their associated costs.

If the best result still has a super-high cost, it means that the planner found no strategy to avoid the sequential scan, even when trying  *at all costs*.

In the plan shown in the question under "Index plan with buffers" this happens at the **Seq Scan on foxtrot** node.